# Indesign GREP - find lines before a string but exclude string

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

I am struggling to find some GREP to find lines before a string when I need to exclude the string itself from the selection.

In this example, I need to find the 2 lines before "Fox", but exclude "Fox" itself.

```
Apple   
Banana   
Carrot   
Duck  
Egg  
Fox  
Giraffe
```

"((.*(\n)){2})Fox" returns "Duck Egg Fox", so I just need to exclude "Fox" from the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookaheads in InDesign GREP queries, so you can just search for:

```
(.*\n){2}(?=Fox)
```

That will match `Duck[break]Egg[break]` (with the line breaks).

Some of the parentheses in your regex expression are not necessary, unless you need to capture each line as a subexpression as well.

(If your lines are delimited by paragraph marks, you would of course use `\r` instead of `\n`.)

Comment: Thanks for your time Janus - it worked exactly as I hoped